# Visual Studio communication with SQL Server -- Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

**I'm having trouble with Visual Studio connecting with SQL Server...
From this code:**

```
public ActionResult SearchByRestaurant()
{
    User objUser = new User();

    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
        objUser = objContext.ContextUser.Find(id);
    }

    objUser.SearchResult = new List<SearchResult>();
    objUser.PreferencesList = objContext.ContextPreferences.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList()
    objUser.RestaurantListAll = objContext.ContextRestaurant.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList();

    if (objUser.SelectedPreferences == null)
        objUser.SelectedPreferences = new int[] { };

    return View(objUser);
}
```

**I'm getting an exception for this line:**

```
objUser.PreferencesList = objContext.ContextPreferences.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList()
```

**Exception:**

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Login failed for user 'sa'.

**I've tried going into the settings to add the 'sa' user as a connection but it isn't working.
Further details:**

- Working with Visual Studio ASP .Net Framwork
- Writing in C#
- Using a basic SQL Server database that is already setup in VS

**I really appreciate any help that can be given, and if you're willing enough to help me further please message me. Thank you!**

**I tried enabling the 'sa' account, and am now receiving this error:**

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

**Connection String:**

```
<configSections> <section name="entityFramework"
type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /> 
</configSections> <connectionStrings> <add name="ContextClass" 
connectionString="Data Source=(local);Persist Security 
Info=True;database=db_FoodAllergy;User ID=sa;Password=saa" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: If I remember correctly sa will be the admin of the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to provide a login credentials on your local sql server. So try to use this connection string. It would work for you..

```
Data Source=(local);database=db_FoodAllergy;Integrated Security=true; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient
```